# I want to print my logfile data into html.erb file

Tags: ruby, logging

```
def cookies_conscent_log
    logger = Logger.new("conscent.log")
    logger.debug "IP Address: " + @country_ip + " | Country: " + @country_name + " | Consent status : " + @deliveries + " | Cookie type : " + @a + " | Time and date: #{Time.now.strftime("[%Y_%m_%d %H:%M:%S]")}".         values printing in log file
    logger.debug "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
end
```

This is my controller method code used to get the values from Ajax call which I am printing in the log file. I am using Logger in rails to print the log file. The same data in my log file needs to be print on html.erb file. I want to display logfile data in tabular format that is why I am trying to get it in HTML file from log file. Is there any way to print logfile data into html.erb file.